# Y axis plotting values not coming as incremental order in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, charts, jqplot

I want to try to plot line chart in PrimeFaces(Version: 6.0.0).
when I see the graph, I could see that Y-Axis values are not displaying in orderly.

Here is my attached chart [[image: screenshot]].

Could anyone help me why it is not displaying ?

Xhtml:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{BackingBean.lineCurrentLineChart}"
rendered="#{not empty BackingBean.lineCurrentLineChart}" id="liveChart" style="height:500px;width:500px" />
```

BackingBean.java

```
public void CurrentExecutionLiveChart()
{
    if(lineCurrentLineChart != null)
    {
        lineCurrentLineChart.clear();
    }
    lineCurrentLineChart = new LineChartModel();


    Axis Yaxis = new CategoryAxis("Execution Time in Minutes");
    Yaxis.setMin(0);
    Yaxis.setMax(59);
    Yaxis.setTickFormat("%d");
    Yaxis.setTickInterval("5");
    lineCurrentLineChart.getAxes().put(AxisType.Y, Yaxis);


    Axis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("Scenario Name");
    xAxis.setTickAngle(-90);        
    lineCurrentLineChart.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);

    LineChartSeries ch = new LineChartSeries();

    ch.setLabel("ScenarioList");
    ch.set("Sce_1", 0);
    ch.set("Sce_2", 16);
    ch.set("Sce_3", 18);
    ch.set("Sce_4", 12);
    ch.set("Sce_5", 4);
    ch.set("Sce_6", 32);
    ch.set("Sce_7", 12);
    ch.set("Sce_8", 0);
    ch.set("Sce_9", 0);
    ch.set("Sce_10", 10);
    ch.set("Sce_11", 0);
    ch.set("Sce_12", 0);


    lineCurrentLineChart.addSeries(ch); 
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Hope, these details is enough to analyst question.

Comment: So it works if you don't use `ConvertHHMMSStoMinutes` but put the converted minutes in manually?

Comment: No, It gives the same sequence number if i use manually also.

Comment: So your [mcve] can be more 'minimal'... and what if you remove even more? The setMin and setMax? no explicit category axis? Did you read what it does?

Comment: And I improved your tagging.

Comment: You want me to understand what is setMin and setMax functionality? also read "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" link to understand how to post a question ?

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje for your help, It was a problem in Category part. I have posted an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to update you on the asked question. Problem was in     `Axis Yaxis = lineCurrentLineChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y);`

I should not have created Yaxis using category class. Hence after changing     `Axis Yaxis = lineCurrentLineChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y);` to      `Axis Yaxis = lineCurrentLineChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y);`

My problem solved.

I am attaching correct chart image. for your reference

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKbku.png)

Here is the solution,

```
    Axis Yaxis = lineCurrentLineChart.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    Yaxis.setLabel("Execution Time in Minutes");
    Yaxis.setMin(0);
    Yaxis.setMax(100);
    Yaxis.setTickFormat("%d");
    Yaxis.setTickInterval("5");     

    Axis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("Scenario Name");
    xAxis.setTickAngle(-90);        
    lineCurrentLineChart.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, xAxis);
```

Thank you @Kukelje

Comment: Great it works, hope you create  a [mcve] directly on your next question (I 'improved' it, but using info from your comment, please take a look so it is even more minimal as commented). And please re-read your answer, there is some duplicate code and other code missing